# change text color with background with Js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating thumbs up button with anchor tag when the user click on it, it background and font color change but the problem is it is changing the background color but not the font color:

```js
function changeColor() {
  document.getElementById('icon').style.color = "#fff"; // forecolor
  document.getElementById('icon').style.background = "#008000"; // backcolor
}
```

```css
.thumb-up {
  border: 5px solid green;
  width: 42%;
  padding: 30px 6px 34px 32px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="changeColor()" href="#">
  <div id="icon" class="thumb-up">
    <i id="icon" class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-5x"></i>
  </div>
</a>
```

**Problem:** I want to change text and background color on click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `id="icon"` twice, this is a crime in HTML and that's the reason it doesn't work. Change it to `class` or give different values for `id`.

```
<div id="icon" class="thumb-up">
  <i id="icon" class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-5x"></i>
  <!--^^^^^^^^ -->
</div>
```

In this case, you may as well remove the `id="icon"` from `<i>` tag. Also, there are CSS based solutions for this, if you are up for it. They are more effective.

**Clarification from OP**

I used the following code. Also, you should not use `fas` and I changed to `fa`. I get this initially:

[image: initial]

Upon clicking, I get this:

[image: click]

This is the full code I used:

```js
function changeColor() {
  document.getElementById('icon').style.color = "#fff"; // forecolor
  document.getElementById('icon').style.background = "#008000"; // backcolor
}
```

```css
.thumb-up {
  border: 5px solid green;
  width: 42%;
  padding: 30px 6px 34px 32px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<a onclick="changeColor()" href="#">
  <div id="icon" class="thumb-up">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up fa-5x"></i>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185828/discussion-on-answer-by-praveen-kumar-purushothaman-change-text-color-with-backg).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use same `id` names. Id names should be unique.

Your code is working fine here with changes.

```js
function changeColor() {
  document.getElementById('icons').style.color = "#fff"; // forecolor
  document.getElementById('icon').style.background = "#008000"; // backcolor
}
```

```css
.thumb-up {
  border: 5px solid green;
  width: 42%;
  padding: 30px 6px 34px 32px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="changeColor()" href="#">
  <div id="icon" class="thumb-up">
    <i id="icons" class="fas fa-thumbs-up fa-5x">&#x2713;</i>
  </div> 
</a>
```

I've changed the id name for fa-icon to `icons` so that it will be an unique name

Comment: You changed the icon?

Comment: I changed icon's id name!

Comment: I meant this: `&#x2713;`.  `:)`

Comment: I didn't import font-awesome css here so I used unicode for that. :)

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: @Viira Ah okay! `:)`

Comment: @faseeh Anyway, check out my answer mate. I have added some more clarification.